# ORA-01017 invalid username/password logon denied

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I am working on a homework problem. I need to get Oracle 12c working with sqldeveloper on Windows and I'm getting:

> Test failed: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied.

Steps I've tried:

1. `alter user sys as identified by "<password>"`, then `alter user sys account unlock`
2. `Select username/password from dba_users` - this gives me an output that looks very unclean, i.e. the format

   ```
   USERNAME
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 

   PASSWORD
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   THINK THIS IS A USERNAME

   THINK THIS IS A PASSWORD
   ```

SOME WORDS

This repeats itself. Assuming the first response is a username and the second is a password, I have tried various combinations of the two. Then I have tried various combinations of the first and third, still no luck. I have unlocked multiple accounts, used quite a few of them. no luck.

3. Found my tsnames.ora, I don't see anything that looks like a username and password. I do see that it's using localhost and port 1521, which I have in my SQL Developer
4. Ran `Select instance from v$thread;` in SQL and got back orcl, used that as my SID
5. Tried various connection types, including PDBORCL and PDBORCL doesn't seem to be an option for me.
6. Tried to re-install Oracle 12g, I don't see anywhere where it had asked me for a username. It did ask for a password under global db name. I tried a combination of that password and either SYS or my oracle account online, nothing.
7. Set my tnsnames directory in advanced settings under preferences in sql developer
8. Tried to unlock the scott/tiger account - this doesn't seem to be a valid account in 12g
9. Requested a new password from https://profile.oracle.com, tried that. Same error.
10. Tried the instructions here, no dice: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/os-authentication
11. ran lsnrctl status  and confirmed sql is running
12. Looked at quite a few stack overflow links
13. Got the container name as CDB$ROOT and ID of 1. Added 
    USE_SID_AS_SERVICE_CDB$ROOT=on in my listener.ora file and restarted lsnrctl

My tnsnames.ora:

```
LISTENER_ORCL =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))


ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS_LIST =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
)
(CONNECT_DATA =
  (SID = CLRExtProc)
  (PRESENTATION = RO)
)
)

ORCL =
```

(DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl.national.x.com)
    )
   )

Comment: sys won't work with the password unless you add the AS SYSDBA string to your connection - otherwise the password you supply at install time applies to both SYS and SYSTEM users...and once you're in as those, you can change the passwords for ANY account on the db

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 7):

OK! So if Oracle doesn't prompt you for a username, the default username is SYSTEM.

SO! 
Username: SYSTEM
Password: The password i entered on creating the Db (or my account pw, i named them both the same)
sid must be orcl, if not set it as above
localhost and port must match whats in tnsnames.ora

And that solves it! Hopefully someone else will find this helpful and not go down as many rabbit holes as I did

Comment: I am glad to see that you find a solution for your problem, However, I don't understand neither your question nor your answer - thank goodness you did out by yourself!

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit well that's how students work these days.

Comment: I posted the error I was getting, I'm not sure how much more clear I could make it:  Test failed: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied.

Comment: I think I understand the question and answer because I've ran it, but i would definitely suggest cleaning up the wording if you expect anyone to get anything from it